# C# Predefined namespaces and methods

Tags: c#

So, I am kind of new to C# and i want to go in depth and learn about it. I need someone to help me with a link to a webpage or book or something that contains the predefined namespaces, classes and methods/functions for C#. Been searching on the internet but the results are either specific to a part of C# (Example: string as a data type and its methods) or they just show how to create a class or method. Therefore, I'd really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you talking about nuget packages??

Comment: Well I mean the framework is pretty well documented over on msdn.

Comment: I don't know what nuget means in this context. But Packages in java? Yes. Only its called namespaces in C#. That's why i used 'namespaces'.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne Thanks. Have you got a link?

Comment: @Shully [Here you go](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks a whole lot. @EdPlunkett I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called the Base Class Library, it's the part of .NET that contains the types you are describing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045(v=vs.110).aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netframework-4.7

Comment: Thanks very much. I really really appreciate. All the best in whatever you're doing. And thanks again.  :-)

Comment: No worries. You can mark this as the accepted answer if it's helpful.

Comment: No problem. It's done. :-) :-)  Thanks again.